# Как в боте реализовать рандомную отправку конкретных фраз из текстовика?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Мне нужно чтобы из текстового файла брались заранее заготовленные фразы рандомно и отправлялись в мною указанный промежуток времени. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В указанный промежуток времени - `crontab` или `shedule`  в помощь. Рандомные фразы - помещаете, к примеру все в список, и выбираете рандомный элемент. Первое, что пришло в голову

Comment: те пронумеровать их в текстовике?

Comment: @KonnerR, нет. Тот вариант, который я предложил - собрать из текстового документа список. Можно сделать и циклом `for` открыв файл на чтение `r` и каждую строку записать в список `my_list.append('phrase')`. Если файл небольшой - самому собрать список со значениями. Как-то так. Но неизвестно, в каком порядке и как у вас находятся там слова в файле, поэтому это только одно из предполагаемых решений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, в файле `phrases.txt` есть набор готовых ответов; на одной строчке - один ответ.

Пусть наш бот будет отправлять рандомные фразы из `phrases.txt` каждые 10 минут.


Для парсинга файла я буду использовать функцию `file.readlines()`, вот ссылка на документацию: https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/metody-fajlovogo-obekta-potoka-python/metod-file-readlines/

Для того, чтобы бот отправлял сообщения в промежуток времени, есть 2 способа: `crontab` или `time.sleep()`. Я покажу второй вариант.


**phrases.txt**

```
Привет, человек!
А я что, знаю что ли?
Как твои дела?
```

**main.py**

```
# Импортируем библиотеки
import telebot
import random
import time

# Инициализируем бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
CHAT_ID = # сюда надо вписать ID чата в который бот будет 

while True:
    phrases = open("phrases.txt", "r") # Откроем файл для чтения
    content_list = phrases.readlines() 
    '''
    Функция прочитает файл и разобьёт его построчно
    content_list = ['Привет, человек!\n', 'А я что, знаю что ли?\n', 'Как твои дела?\n']
    '''
    bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, random.choice(content_list)) # Выбираем рандомную фразу из списка и отправляем её в чат
    time.sleep(600) # 600 - 10 минут в секундах


# Запускаем бота
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: мне выдает ошибку "content_list" is not defined